# Populate Select dropdownlist in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, select, arraylist

Here is my code to populate select tag  using arraylist values

First The Dao looks like

```
     public List<Student> getStudents() {

    String hql = "FROM Student";
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    List queryResults = query.list();
    List<Student> result = new ArrayList<Student>();

    Iterator it = queryResults.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Student student = (Student) it.next();
        result.add(student);
    }
    session.close();
    return result;
}
```

And controller

```
   public ModelAndView select() {

    List<Student> students = service.getStudents();
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("select",
            "students", students);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

and the jsp page

```
     <body>
   <select>
  <c:forEach var="student" items="${students}">
    <option value="${student.id}">${student.name}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
   </body>
```

Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: Questions about improving working code belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Your code looks fine to me, but you have left out a lot of details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
     <body>
         <form:form ... >
           <form:select path="" items="${students}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"/>
         </form:form>   
     </body>
```